# AS3 - PixelBender Shader ArgumentError

Tags: actionscript-3, shader, pixel-bender

I'm having a problem and it's getting really annoying. I want to use a simple `Shader` to return the colours of all the pixels in an image, but simply assigning a script to a `Shader` is proving to be a challenge.
I don't know PixelBender script and I don't intend to study it too much since I only want to use it for this simple function, but from examples I've constructed this simple script:

```
<languageVersion : 1.0;>

kernel PixelColourShader
<   namespace : "puggsoy";
    vendor : "Puggsoy";
    version : 1;
>
{
    input image4 src;
    output pixel4 dst;

    void
    evaluatePixel()
    {
        dst = sampleNearest(src, outCoord());
    }
}
```

Here's a simple AS3 script I made to test loading it:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Shader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = "PixelColourShader.pbj", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
        private var PixelColourShader:Class;

        private var shader:Shader;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            shader = new Shader(new PixelColourShader() as ByteArray);
        }

    }

}
```

I've looked over numerous examples and I'm sure this is the correct way to load it. However, this always gives this error at runtime:

```
[Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
```

and I have no idea why. From what I can see the parameter is completely valid.

I'm making this in an AIR application with FlashDevelop using the Flex 4 SDK.

Comment: That is odd. I can't suggest much, but I just tested your code in Flash CS5.5 and it compiled and ran fine, so I don't think you're doing anything wrong there (and the kernel itself is obviously nearly identical to the template script).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var shaderShader = new Shader();
 shader.byteCode = new PixelColourShader();
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, I get the same result. Also there's a mistake in your code, it should be `shader` not `shaderShader`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like Adobe Pixel Bender to compile your text file into a binary pbj.